# When using jar package, Runtime.getRuntime().exec does not work to get bash_profile environment variable

Tags: java, flutter, shell, intellij-idea

I am using **intellij IDEA** to develop an **AndroidStudio Plugin**. The function of the plugin is to create a **flutter plugin**.

I have written a shell script, which uses `flutter create` to create a **flutter plugin**. Then I wrote the code to call the script in **intellij IDEA**, and everything worked here. What I mean is that using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` can call shell scripts normally, and it can also meet my expectations.

```java
public static class ShellUtil {
        public static String runShell(String shStr) throws Exception {
            Process process;
            String[] command = new String[] {"bash","-c",shStr};
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            String result = "";
            while ((line = read.readLine())!=null){
                result+=line;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

But after I compiled it into a **jar package** and installed it in **AndroidStudio**, everything changed. The PATH I printed out was only `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, I can be sure that I added **flutter** to the PATH of `bash_profile`. I searched a lot of information, and it seems to be saying that java has opened a new shell process, and this process cannot get all the environment variables of **bash_profile**.

My question is: How can I get the environment variables in **bash_profile** in the java shell process?

Latest development: I execute `source ~/.bash_profile` at the beginning of the shell file, and I can get the environment variables I want. But it does not mean that my PATH is not effective. Before adding, I restarted the computer and run **intellij IDEA** to ensure that the environment variables in **bash_profile** are all effective.

Although I can execute export PATH before executing the script in java, this is not what I want, because the path for installing flutter is different for everyone, and I hope to get the result of `which flutter`.

Comment: This is normal, and in fact behaving by-design. `.bash_profile` is used for _login_ shells. It's not expected or intended to be sourced for noninteractive shells, or even interactive non-login shells.

Comment: You don't **want** a user's dotfiles to be taking effect in your scripts -- it makes the behavior of the shell unpredictable; users do all kinds of weird things.

Comment: ...that said, the `PATH` should be inherited from the parent process; so ideally, user logs in -> PATH is set by their login shell -> PATH is inherited from the login shell by Android Studio -> every program Android Studio runs inherits the PATH that it inherited from the login shell. However, that only works until/unless some program tries to _explicitly override_ that PATH, and it wouldn't be all that unusual for the IDE to support enforcing an explicitly configured one.

Comment: *Unrelated:* 1) You need to move the `process.waitFor();` statement down after the `while` loop. --- 2) You should use try-with-resources to close `read`.

Comment: Anyhow -- I would strongly suggest reframing this question. Don't worry about honoring `.bash_profile` -- it _shouldn't_ be honored, because typically dotfiles will do a bunch of things intended only for interactive use -- instead worry about passing the parent process PATH through unmodified.

Comment: Repeating myself, since an edit to the question implies this was unclear: The PATH set by `.bash_profile` is by default (absent an application doing something to change this, which it sounds like IntelliJ / Android Studio may be doing) passed to child processes _even when those processes don't themselves run `.bash_profile`_. That's what you want. Don't try to make the child process run `.bash_profile`; instead, make the child process use the value it inherits without overriding it.

Comment: BTW -- what's your operating system? What I described is the general rule, but if you started Android Studio from a GUI framework and that GUI wasn't launched in a way that let a login shell change its environment, that general rule may not hold. (If this is Linux, you can check `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/$PID/environ` for different processes' PIDs to walk the process tree and see where the PATH changes from the one you want to the one you don't).

Comment: To force loading of `~/.bash_profile`, add option **`--login`**, i.e. use `String[] command = {"bash","--login","-c",shStr};` *(note that you don't need the `new String[]` in an initializer)*.

Comment: @Andreas, ...it _works_, but that's by no means good practice. A lot of folks source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc` contains all manner of garbage. The Right Thing is to let the inherited value be passed through to the child.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for your timely return, my operating system is MacOS. What you mean is that environment variables are obtained from the parent process and passed to the current child process. Is this understanding correct? But I am not yet familiar with how to get environment variables from the parent process.

Comment: @Nullable, unless a program goes out of its way, getting environment variables from the parent process is _automatic_. When a program calls `fork()` or `clone()` to make a copy of itself, that copy is _always_ provided with a copy of the parent's environment variables.

Comment: @Nullable, ...that's why I'm speculating that Android Studio is likely to be going out of its way to set a new collection of variables -- it's either that, or the Finder isn't started in a way that honors your dotfiles during login, so things started by the Finder don't see them; that's plausible too.

Comment: @Nullable, ...see [How to set PATH for Finder-launched applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications) on [apple.se], confirming that if you start your IDE from Finder, it doesn't see contents of `.bash_profile`. (That's very much a MacOS issue -- traditionally Linux-y systems will honor your shell's profile during user session initialization).

Comment: (tl;dr: apparently on MacOS the Right Way to persist a PATH change is with `launchctl config user path "$PATH"`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much, you save my day.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks also for your answer